# Monty Hall problem again (from Grimmett and Stirzaker)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recreational-mathematics, monty-hall

Grimmett and Stirzaker Exercise 1.4.5.2

> In a game show you have to choose one of three doors. One conceals a car, 2 conceal goats. You choose a door but the door is not opened immediately. Instead the presenter opens another door, which reveals a goat. He offers you the opportunity to change your choice to the third door (unopened and so far unchosen ). Let $p$ be the conditional probability that the third door conceals the car. The presenter's protocol is:
>
> (i) he is determined to show you a goat; with a choice of two, he picks one at random. Show that $p=2/3$
>
> (ii)he is determined to show you a goat; with a choice of two goats (Billy and Nan), he shows Billy with probability b. Show that $p=\frac{1}{1+b}$
>
> (iii) he opens a door at random irrespective of what is behind. Show that $p=1/2$

I understand (i) but not (ii).

For (i) my answer is:

> Label the doors D1,D2,D3, the car C, the goats G1 and G2, a goat G
>
> then
>
> $P(D3=C|D2=G)=\frac {P(D3=C \  \cap\ D2=G)} {P(D2=G)}=\frac{P(D3=C\ \cap D2=G | D1=C)  P(D1=C) + P(D3=C\ \cap\ D2=G | D1 \neq C) P(D1 \neq C) }{P(D2=G |D1=C)P(D1=C)+P(D2=G|D1 \neq C)P(D1\neq C)}=\frac{0*{1\over3}+1 * {2\over3}}{1*{1\over3}+1*{2\over3}}={2\over3}$

however similarly for (ii) my answer would be (calling Billy G1):

> $P(D3=C|D2=G1)=\frac {P(D3=C \  \cap \ D2=G1)} {P(D2=G1)}=\frac{P(D3=C\ \cap D2=G1 | D1=C)  P(D1=C) + P(D3=C \ \cap D2=G1 | D1 \neq C) P(D1 \neq C) }{P(D2=G1 |D1=C)P(D1=C)+P(D2=G1|D1 \neq C)P(D1\neq C)}=\frac{0*{1\over3}+{1\over2}*{2\over3}}{b*{1\over3}+1*{2\over3}}=\frac{1}{b+2}$

where is my mistake ?

[Note: this question has undergone some changes in wording over successive editions of the book, in an attempt at clarifying the problem statement, as seen in the comments below. I attempted to answer what I believe was the problem intended by the authors.]

Comment: You misquoted the problem. [Here](https://books.google.de/books?id=G3ig-0M4wSIC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA12#v=onepage&q&f=false)'s the correct problem. It says "Show that, given you see Bill, the probability is $1/(1+b)$".

Comment: Is that different from the calculation I carried out?

Comment: Also I have re-checked, the problem statement in my version of the book (3rd edition) is exactly as written.

Comment: OK, sorry, for jumping to conclusions. Unfortunately the more common occurrence here is that problems regularly get misquoted. I'll make up for it by answering the question later today :-)

Comment: Thanks, @joriki.  I spent about ten minutes looking at the problem this way and that and trying to figure out how the identity of a goat you don't even recognize could possibly affect the probability of the car being behind the third door.

Comment: i think the error is that P(D2=G1|D1<>C)=1/2 in the last term in the denominator , just like I put in the numerator -- that gives 1/(1+b), although i will await the official answer :)

Comment: I think it might be worth editing your question and mentioning that your calculation is an attempt to answer the question the authors intended to ask, rather than the one they did ask (as evidenced by the change in wording in the 4th edition).    I wouldn't change the text you have, since the comments refer to it, but maybe add something at the end.  I was confused about this point for quite a while, and imagine future readers might be as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation is a bit confusing (at least to me), since I would usually expect $D_1$ to $D_3$ to refer to specific doors (e.g. the first, second and third door from the left), whereas if I understand your calculations correctly, you're using them to refer, respectively, to "the door I picked", "the door the presenter opened" and "the door I could switch to". That's fine, but you should have explained it.

With that interpretation, your calculations, corrected as per your comment, are correct. You could have saved yourself a lot of trouble in case (i), though, since in that case it's clear from the protocol that $D_2$ will always have a goat, so you could have dropped $D_2=G$ everywhere and just written

\begin{align}
P(D_3=C)&=P(D_3=C\mid D_1=C)P(D_1=C)+P(D_3=C\mid D_1\ne C)P(D_1\ne C)\\
&=0\cdot\frac13+1\cdot\frac23\\
&=\frac23\;.
\end{align}

Comment: Yes indeed this labeling of the door (D1=door i picked, D2=door the host chooses, D3=door i could switch to) is what i meant - sorry.